# Word to describe someone that has posted "proof"

Tags: meaning, american-english, british-english, example

Pretend locks cannot be picked.

What would be a word to describe someone that has spent a long time writing an article full of absolute nonsense which they think is correct, believing for some reason that they are right, and influencing people due to the formal/professional way the article/blog/post etc... is wrote?

Assume it's nonsense as it is something stupid like putting a screwdriver into a lock and twisting it will open the lock. Except even in the information they post they do not successfully open the lock, despite a 10 page report with stupid information such as "you here cracks that means the lock is weak and about to open".

They might open lock in the end with the key, but my point is everything about what they have said is horse s**t to put this clearly.

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for a single word adjective to describe a person. However please note that when asking for single word suggestions you should provide an example sentence where it will be used, using blanks or underscores in place of the word you need.

Comment: 'wrong' isn't enough?

Comment: I am confused by your lock metaphor (I am even unsure if it is supposed to be a metaphor...). I am also unclear about the relation of your title to the question. I am assuming the paper is supposed to be a proof of a conjecture that advocates a *brute force* method of proof, which method doesn't even work?

Comment: *Smoke and mirrors* comes to mind (here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_and_mirrors)

Comment: Semiotician?  Literary critic?  Deconstructionist?

Comment: @Silenus Pretend bruteforce is impossible, and the person that wrote the paper couldn't even show their method working as it's impossible.

Comment: *"Misguided"* - but that does not convey spending a lot of time writing nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

It does not exactly fit the bill, but I suggest **pseudo-scientist** [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/pseudoscientist)

> **pseudo-science**
>
> *noun* A system of theories, assumptions, and methods erroneously regarded as scientific